# Telerik:RadGrid disabled refresh

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I'm working with `telerik:RadGrid` when I click the button in a column should open a `RadWindow` and apparently does not work because of the refresh button .

How can I disable the update?

Comment: Do you mean the refresh button in the grid header or you mean a postback is happening you press the button?

Comment: I wanna say in the postback Button in the grid .. for example, a Button open a popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

In `.aspx code` had a tag `<AjaxUpdatedControl>` make reference with a `<telerik:Radgrid>`, I just remove tag `<AjaxUpdatedControl>` and I obtained success.